# PHP Post inquiry from HTML select tag

Tags: php, html, post, select

I have an HTML Select Block in a Form, that should send some Data when submitted.

The whole Database Connection works fine, and also the If- Statement foer the submit button. 
When i just include the 
echo 'test'; 
it works perfectly and gives me the string.

But as I include the line
`echo $_POST['Semester'];`
even when i just write it to a variable like 
`$testvar = $_POST['Semester'];`

it doesnt work. 
I tried renaming variables and changing values, but everytime it click on the submit, it gives me a *503 can't currently handle this request* Error.

Is there a stupid mistake that I cant see, or could that maybe be an issue of my Webhost (Strato.de)?

I tried changing the php.ini file but theres nothing i can find that helps with my problem.
I also changed the security settings with Strato, so in general, Post inquiries are accepted and also User Scripts are allowed.

I tried to do a minimal working Example, as I uncomment the `$_POST` line, it stops working. Without it, it does.
[Btw this is a userscript for a phpBB website, thats why theres all the database stuff in the front]

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="Semester">
<option value="test">choice</option>
<option value="test">choice2</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<!-- PHP -->
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);

include($phpbb_root_path . 'config.' . $phpEx);
//Datenbank scheiss
$db = new mysqli('rdbms.strato.de', $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   //echo $_POST['Semester'];
   //$chd= $_POST['child'];
   echo 'test';
   //echo $pari;
}

?>

<!-- ENDPHP -->
```

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST);` to see what your page is actually receiving.  And check your logs to see what is going on server side.

Comment: Thanks,, for the answer. The problem is, 503 is not logged in the errorlogs unfortunately.
The ```printr``` gives out a lt of random stuff, is there something in particular I should look at? if I put ```printr($_POST['Semester'])``` I still receive a 503, and the browser also doesn't give me any valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, deleting the Style tags before I start the php file, solved the issue. 
Dont know if its an issue with php or phpBB as my backend. It works now